# How to make colors stay the same on dark mode gmail (ios/android) email?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, darkmode

I've spent a lot of time reading on the topic, from blend-modes, meta tags, css queries but nothing worked. I personally like dark mode, and try to set it everywhere I can, but I understand that light theme is still the standard. I also find it useful that instead of developers having to explicitly set the colors for dark, and light modes separately, those are being calculated by the app.

However I find it annoying that there's no option to manually set how some elements should be colored in dark, and light modes. Brands have design guidelines, and it looks awful when these are auto-transformed to something completely different. I'm looking for a method to make some colors stay the same in light, and dark mode as well.

Comment: You could use Stylus [(Firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) [(Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) to write your own CSS for gmail.